# (Probability : Theory and Examples, Durrett ) Theorem 5.2.2 Monotone Class Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

Theorem 5.2.2 is as below.

> (Monotone class theorem) Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\pi$-system that contiains $\Omega$ and let $\mathcal{H}$ be a collection of real-valued functions that satisfies:
> (1) If $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $1_A \in \mathcal{H}$
> (2) If $f,g \in \mathcal{H}$, then $f+g$ and $cf\in \mathcal{H}$ for any real number $c$
> (3) If $f_n \in \mathcal{H}$ are non-negative and increase to a bounded function $f$, then $f\in \mathcal{H}$
> Then $\mathcal{H}$ contains all bounded functions measurable with respect to $\sigma (\mathcal{A})$

In the proof, it says that (2) and (3) implies that $\mathcal{G} = \{A:1_A\in\mathcal{H}\}$ is a $\lambda$-system. I can't understand how (2) and (3) is related to $\lambda$-system.
How can we show the complement and disjoint countable union conditions satisfy?

Comment: You did not quote the full result. The proof of the theorem in Durret will tell you how things are linked. (3) is the analog to $\lambda$ systems being closed under union of monotone sequences of sets; (2) is more algebraic but is somewhat parallel to the property of $\lambda$ families being closed under proper differences. Just read the proof and if you still have questions, then ask the specific part you don't understand.

Comment: If $A\subset B$ and $A,B\in \mathcal{H}$ then by (2) $B\setminus A\in\mathcal{H}$ for $\mathbb{1}_{B\setminus A}=\mathbb{1}_B-\mathbb{1}_A$. If $A_n\in\mathcal{H}$ and $A_n\nearrow A$, then (3) says that $A\in\mathcal{H}$. So $\mathcal{H}$ is indeed a $\lambda$-system.

Comment: I added the full result! What I didn't catch was the properties of simple function. Now I got it!Thank you very much for the details and the intuitive explanation